# My Screen is black and React-Router is Not Working , I am stuck in between , Browser is not showing anything

Tags: reactjs, react-router

> Uncaught Error: [Homepage] is not a `<Route>` component. All component
> children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

Can someone tell me what is wrong exactly.?! i am trying to output my website  but i am unable to do so.I am getting blank screen , Please help me !

HomePage.jsx

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import Header from "../../components/header/Header";
import Posts from "../../components/posts/Posts";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import "./homepage.css";
import React from 'react'
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default function Homepage() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="home">
        <Posts />
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Single from "./pages/single/Single";
import Write from "./pages/write/Write";
import Settings from "./pages/settings/Settings";
import Topbar from "./components/topbar/Topbar";
import Homepage from "./pages/homepage/Homepage";
import Login from "./pages/login/Login";
import Register from "./pages/register/Register";
import {  Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const currentUser = true;
  return (
   
    // {/* //Router k andar dala jata hn  */}
    // {/* Topbar me no changing ya switching */}
    <>
      <Topbar />
      <Routes>
      {/* //exact likhne se exactly wo likhne pe hi work krega */}
   
        <Route exact path="/"
          element={Homepage }
        />
        <Route path="/posts">
          <Homepage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
          {currentUser ? <Homepage /> : <Register />}
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">{currentUser ? <Homepage /> : <Login />}</Route>
        <Route path="/post/:id">
          <Single />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/write">{currentUser ? <Write /> : <Login />}</Route>
        <Route path="/settings">
          {currentUser ? <Settings /> : <Login />}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from './App';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Please Help me , Following codes are of index.js , App.js and HomePage.jsx. The above error is showing..**

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` components render their content on the `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. The only valid children of a `Route` component is another nested `Route` component.

Move the children onto the `element` prop.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Homepage /> } />
  <Route path="/posts" element={<Homepage />} />
  <Route
    path="/register"
    element={currentUser ? <Homepage /> : <Register />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/login"
    element={currentUser ? <Homepage /> : <Login />}
  />
  <Route path="/post/:id" element={<Single />} />
  <Route
    path="/write"
    element={currentUser ? <Write /> : <Login />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/settings"
    element={currentUser ? <Settings /> : <Login />}
  />
</Routes>
```

Protecting routes is common enough you will want to abstract the `currentUser` check into a layout route that renders an `Outlet` for nested routes you want to protect.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = ({ currentUser }) => {
  if (currentUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return currentUser
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

const AnonymousLayout = ({ currentUser }) => {
  if (currentUser === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return currentUser
    ? <Navigate to="/" replace />
    : <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Homepage /> } />
  <Route path="/posts" element={<Homepage />} />
  <Route path="/post/:id" element={<Single />} />

  <Route element={<AnonymousLayout currentUser={currentUser} />}>
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  </Route>

  <Route element={<AuthLayout currentUser={currentUser} />}>
    <Route path="/write" element={<Write />} />
    <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```